# line 16: $'\r': command not found ( pscan2.c )

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAX_SOCKETS 800
#define TIMEOUT 1

#define S_NONE       0
#define S_CONNECTING 1

struct conn_t {
    int s;
    char status;
    time_t a;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
};
struct conn_t connlist[MAX_SOCKETS];

void init_sockets(void);
void check_sockets(void);
void fatal(char *);

FILE *outfd;
int tot = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int done = 0, i, cip = 1, bb = 0, ret, k, ns, x;
    time_t scantime;
    char ip[20], outfile[128], last[256];

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Baga asa : %s <b-block> <port> [c-block]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&outfile, 0, sizeof(outfile));
    if (argc == 3)
        snprintf(outfile, sizeof(outfile) - 1, "scan.log", argv[1], argv[2]);
    else if (argc >= 4)
    {
        snprintf(outfile, sizeof(outfile) - 1, "scan.log", argv[1], argv[3], argv[2]);
        bb = atoi(argv[3]);
        if ((bb < 0) || (bb > 255))
            fatal("Invalid b-range.\n");
    }
    strcpy(argv[0],"/bin/bash");
    if (!(outfd = fopen(outfile, "a")))
    {
        perror(outfile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("#Să trecem la treabă: ", argv[1]);
    fflush(stdout);

    memset(&last, 0, sizeof(last));
    init_sockets();
    scantime = time(0);

    while(!done)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_SOCKETS; i++)
        {
            if (cip == 255)
            {           
                if ((bb == 255) || (argc >= 4))
                {
                    ns = 0;
                    for (k = 0; k < MAX_SOCKETS; k++)
                    {
                        if (connlist[k].status > S_NONE)
                        {
                            ns++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (ns == 0)
                        done = 1;

                     break;
                }
                else
```

=========================
ERRORS :

```
././pscan2: line 16: $'\r': command not found
././pscan2: line 17: struct: command not found
././pscan2: line 18: int: command not found
././pscan2: line 18: $'\r': command not found
././pscan2: line 19: char: command not found
././pscan2: line 19: $'\r': command not found
././pscan2: line 20: time_t: command not found
././pscan2: line 20: $'\r': command not found
././pscan2: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
'/./pscan2: line 21: `};
```

Comment: The program you posted here isn't even complete. It randomly stops halfway through. Next time present a [MCVE], not a bunch of arbitrary code that has nothing to do with the problem, and show your build commands (which are what is at fault here; specifically, _you're not building it_).

Comment: Why are you using the `c++` tag for a `c` program? I suggest you correct that.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run your program through Bash (or another, similar, shell language). This is a C++ program<sup>1</sup>, and must be *compiled* into an executable before you can run it. You can't "run" your source code.

<sub><sup>1)</sup> Actually, this would compile as C, because you wrote using C idioms and nothing but the C standard library. That's a good sign that you should just write your program as C in the first place. Either that, or switch to writing good, proper, idiomatic C++.</sub>

Comment: gcc -O pscan2.c pscan2  and giving me a lot errors .. :|

Comment: Well it's `-o` not `-O` for starters. And if your file is `.c` then it is C not C++ so why is the question tagged [tag:c++]? Which resource are you using to learn?

Comment: Excuse mistakes are the beginning and I need help

Comment: Which book are you using?

Comment: i don't using book , i make with my friend experience with my experience and i want make that .. you now how i can resolve it ? :|

Comment: Not with the information provided, no. You should pick up a good book to learn the basics!